# Add items to list from configurationfile

Tags: asp.net

The current code: manually setting.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Question" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem>What is the city of your birth?</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>What school did you attend for sixth grade?</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>What is your maternal grandmother's maiden name?</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Where were you when you had your first kiss?</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Who was your childhood hero?</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the configuration file, if I put items in

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Question1" value="What is the city of your birth?" />
```

Then how can I retrieve them from code?

Comment: Why do this at all? What will putting it in configuration gain you? Just editing the file will be easier and more maintainable.

Comment: @Love: This is where databases come in handy. Is that an option for you? Or maybe an XML file or something that lives outside of the web.config?

Comment: No database stores these items, I will use sentences many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int i = 1;

string question = null; 

do {
   question = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Question" + i.ToString()]; 

   if (question != null) {
     Question.Items.Add(new ListItem(question, i.ToString()));
     i++;
   }
} while (question != null);
```

Comment: How can I place them in a dropdown menu?

Comment: The code above will put the list into a dropdown list named `Question` as you showed in your example.  The code will also support adding as many questions as you want without having to worry about hard-coding the number of questions available.

Comment: I used CreateUserWizard, could you please look at what is wrong?

Comment: (DropDownList)CreateUserWizardStep2.ContentTemplate.FindControl("Question").Items.Add(new ListItem(question, i.ToString());

Comment: The idea is great, but I got an error: Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. Because I have to find the control "Question".

Comment: No, I figured it out. DropDownList Question=(DropDownList)CreateUserWizardStep2.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Question");
                     Question.Items.Add(new ListItem(question, i.ToString()));

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class and specifically the [AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) property. Like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Question1"];
```

Do not forget to add a reference to `System.Configuration`.